# Switch cursor to show where I can drop an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a question / task that is so obvious that I still wonder why I couldn't find a solution for that...

In a JavaScript application that is using jQuery UI I'm using the `draggable()` and `droppable()` API to be able to move elements around. This works straight forward and as expected.
But now I want to change the mouse cursor in such a way that it shows where I can drop an element (`cursor: "copy"`) or where it's not possible (`cursor: "no-drop"`).

This should - of course - only happen during dragging, otherwise the normal cursor should be shown.

Note: it can be assumed that a drop is only allowed in one special `<div>` (e.g. identified by an `id` or `class`) and everywhere else a drop is not allowed.

Comment: Play a little in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3bbpsj23/) ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the cursor style of the draggable to `no-drop` while dragging using the [start](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start) event callback using [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) method, and change it to `copy` when it is over a droppable within [`over`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over) event callback.

Once the draggable leaves droppable, you can revert the cursor back to `no-drop` within the [`out`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out) event callback, and set reset it back to the default cursor when dragging stops by setting the CSS `cursor` property value to `initial` within the [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) event callback of draggable as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    start: function(event,ui){
     $(this).css("cursor", "no-drop");
    },
    stop: function(event,ui){
     $(this).css("cursor", "initial");
    }
  });
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css("cursor", "copy");
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css("cursor", "no-drop");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
#droppable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">
  <span>Drag</span>
</div>

<div id="droppable">
  <span>Drop here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, thank you very much! All your answers were very helpful and inspired me to a solution that's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qck9kf17/

The "trick" is basically:

```
$('.box').draggable({ cursor: "no-drop" });

$('.container').droppable({
    over: function(){
        $('body').css('cursor','copy');
    },
    out: function(){
        $('body').css('cursor','no-drop');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the dropzone a class (`dropzone`) and when you start dragging add a class to the body element (`draggingInEffect`) via Javascript.

Once you stop dragging remove that class from the body again.

Then add a CSS rule `body.draggingInEffect .dropzone { cursor: url(whatever); }`

Answer (score 1):

Change the cursor while dragging

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ cursor: "crosshair" });
```

Use a hover class when it's over the drop target

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ hoverClass: "drop-hover" });
```

Comment: But how shall this work? The `hoverClass` gets added to the droppable that is below the draggable that is hiding any `cursor` style set in it. Do you have a fiddle that is working?