# show caret (cursor) when dragging div tag in droppable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two divs tag, the first is draggable, the second is droppable and editable.

the snip code as below:

```
<div id='dragElement' draggable='true'>draggble element</div>
<div id='dropElement' droppable='true' contentEditable='true'> 
     droppble and editable element
</div>
```

When i  drag first div into the second, i need to show caret (cursor) at the position of mouse is dragging.
My output likes this:
http://jsfiddle.net/huynhthinh/T2zHQ/86/

Anyone can help me.Thanks all!

Comment: It is *already* shown...

Comment: "mouse pointer" or the "mouse coordinate"?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/zgyaLxhe/
Unfortunately I Think you can't set the cursor property while dragging because browser might set that depending on whether its located over some drop target element. Not sure of that though, so verify that on your own.

Comment: there 's an option to change the cursor type when dragging the element (jquery ui) @ManuelArwedSchmidt

Comment: Good to know that. But no css-only solution, right?

Comment: I think you should see it here http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch cursor to show where I can drop an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071807/switch-cursor-to-show-where-i-can-drop-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

> When i drag first div into the second, i need to show the mouse indicator at the position of mouse is dragging.

You can achieve the same using simple css

try this code

```
#dragElement{
    cursor:move;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvztattw/1/)

Comment: thanks a lot, but i want to show edit indicator at the position cursor is move.

Comment: He wants to change the cursor *ONLY* during drag event, not before or after dragging.

Comment: I think you should see it here @huynhthinh http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style

Comment: and what did you mean with "edit indicator"? @huynhthinh

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi, edit indicator means the indicator when we focus on  
editable div.

Comment: So what is the correlation between draggable/droppable  and 'editing indicator' ? @huynhthinh

Comment: @huynhthinh and what is that..? Please edit your question with more information regarding the expected output, maybe with the help of images or an online demo, rather than commenting below an answer. The information you add below answers are very unlikely to be seen by the rest of community.